# Qooxdoo Access Dynamic Properties from another class?

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm trying to access the selectedObs property of this class:

```
qx.Class.define("edd.view.ObsToggleContainer", {    
extend : qx.ui.container.Composite,
type: "singleton",
properties : {      
    selectedObs : { check: "Array"}
},
construct : function() {...
```

from another class like this:

```
var ObsToggle = edd.view.ObsToggleContainer.getInstance();
console.log(ObsToggle.getSelectedObs());
```

But it seems to not know about what the values are presently set to. Am I doing something wrong or is there some logic that I'm not aware of?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: How and when do you set the value of the property?

Comment: Well, I tried a few different ways (with an init statement, on the class instantiation and after the class was loaded) and none of them seemed to work. I finally found a way that worked which I'll post as the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just making a separate class as just a qx.core.Object and used that instead of a singleton Composite class and it seemed to do what I wanted to accomplish.

```
qx.Class.define("edd.data.DataStore", {
    properties : {      
        checkedObs: { 
            init: [false,  true, true, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false], 
            check: "Array"
        }
    },
    extend : qx.core.Object,
    type: "singleton",

    construct : function() {
        var thisClass = this;
    },

    members :{
    }
});
```

So now, this code properly works:

```
var dataStore = edd.data.DataStore.getInstance();
var init_checked = dataStore.getCheckedObs();
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm. There's something else here. Your initial class definition and the one from your own answer are not far apart, as far as the property is concerned. Maybe in the rest of your initial class, or in the code using it, was something awry?!

Have a look at this [Playground sample](http://bit.ly/GGMztf), which uses your initial class definition. You have to open the "Log" pane, in order to see the output. Works like a charm.

It would be very interesting if you could change this sample, and tweak it until it reproduces your problem?!